# Why is there no room for expectations if the economy is always in equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium, expectations

Joan Robinson ([1972](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1821517)):

> If the economy is always in equilibrium anyway, where is the room for expectations?

Comment: Do you have a more specific question about the article?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no uncertainty in the economy than there's no need to work with expectations. If the economy is always at equilibrium then you will always know the actual values for your variables of interest, meaning you will know for example the price level, output, interest rate  etc